# Unity Game Dev - 'AnimatorHandler' does not contain a definition for 'SetFloat'

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, game-development

I'm following a YouTube tutorial and can't figure out for the life of me why this bug is happening.

**Edit:** In Visual Studio it says no issues found but in Unity it still shows this same bug. Maybe it's a compatibility issue and I need to fix it somehow? Not sure.

Here's the bug that's been happening:

*Assets\AnimatorHandler.cs(73,18): error CS1061: 'AnimatorHandler' does not contain a definition for 'SetFloat' and no accessible extension method 'SetFloat' accepting a first argument of type 'AnimatorHandler' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

**AnimatorHandler.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
namespace JM
{
    public class AnimatorHandler : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public AnimatorHandler anim;
        int vertical;
        int horizontal;
        public bool canRotate;
 
        public void Initialize()
        {
            anim = GetComponent<AnimatorHandler>();
            vertical = Animator.StringToHash("Vertical");
            horizontal = Animator.StringToHash("Horizontal");
        }
 
        public void UpdateAnimatorValues(float verticalMovement, float horizontalMovement)
        {
            #region Vertical
            float v = 0;
 
            if (verticalMovement > 0 && verticalMovement < 0.55f)
            {
                v = 0.5f;
            }
            else if (verticalMovement > 0.55f)
            {
                v = 1;
            }
            else if (verticalMovement < 0 && verticalMovement > -0.55f)
            {
                v = -0.5f;
            }
            else if (verticalMovement < -0.55f)
            {
                v = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                v = 0;
            }
            #endregion
 
            #region Horizontal
            float h = 0;
 
            if (horizontalMovement > 0 && horizontalMovement < 0.55f)
            {
                h = 0.5f;
            }
            else if (horizontalMovement > 0.55f)
            {
                h = 1;
            }
            else if (horizontalMovement < 0 && horizontalMovement > -0.55f)
            {
                h = -0.5f;
            }
            else if (horizontalMovement < -0.55f)
            {
                h = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                h = 0;
            }
            #endregion
 
            anim.SetFloat(vertical, v, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
            anim.SetFloat(horizontal, h, 0.1f, Time.deltaTime);
        }
 
        public void CanRotate()
        {
            canRotate = true;
        }
 
        public void StopRotation()
        {
            canRotate = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**PlayerLocomotion.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
namespace JM
{
    public class PlayerLocomotion : MonoBehaviour
    {
        Transform cameraObject;
        InputHandler inputHandler;
        Vector3 moveDirection;
 
        [HideInInspector]
        public Transform myTransform;
        [HideInInspector]
        public AnimatorHandler animatorHandler;
 
        public new Rigidbody rigidbody;
        public GameObject normalCamera;
 
        [Header("Stats")]
        [SerializeField]
        float movementSpeed = 5;
        [SerializeField]
        float rotationSpeed = 10;
 
        void Start()
        {
            rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            inputHandler = GetComponent<InputHandler>();
            animatorHandler = GetComponentInChildren<AnimatorHandler>();
            cameraObject = Camera.main.transform;
            myTransform = transform;
            animatorHandler.Initialize();
        }
 
        public void Update()
        {
            float delta = Time.deltaTime;
 
            inputHandler.TickInput(delta);
 
            moveDirection = cameraObject.forward * inputHandler.vertical;
            moveDirection += cameraObject.right * inputHandler.horizontal;
            moveDirection.Normalize();
 
            float speed = movementSpeed;
            moveDirection *= speed;
 
            Vector3 projectedVelocity = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(moveDirection, normalVector);
            rigidbody.velocity = projectedVelocity;
 
            if (animatorHandler.canRotate)
            {
                HandleRotation(delta);
            }
 
        }
 
        #region Movement
        Vector3 normalVector;
        Vector3 targetPosition;
 
        private void HandleRotation(float delta)
        {
            Vector3 targetDir = Vector3.zero;
            float moveOverride = inputHandler.moveAmount;
 
            targetDir = cameraObject.forward * inputHandler.vertical;
            targetDir += cameraObject.right * inputHandler.horizontal;
 
            targetDir.Normalize();
            targetDir.y = 0;
 
            if (targetDir == Vector3.zero)
                targetDir = myTransform.forward;
 
            float rs = rotationSpeed;
 
            Quaternion tr = Quaternion.LookRotation(targetDir);
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(myTransform.rotation, tr, rs * delta);
 
            myTransform.rotation = targetRotation;
        }
 
        #endregion
    }
}
```

And here's the tutorial I've been following:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LOC5GJ5rFFw&list=PLD_vBJjpCwJtrHIW1SS5_BNRk6KZJZ7_d&index=7

I tried making sure that all of the names for the AnimatorHandler were spelled correctly and cased correctly but I still can't find out what the problem is. I've also watched the video multiple times to make sure it wasn't something obvious that I was missing but I still can't find anything wrong with the code compared to the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to get the `Animator` inside of AnimatorHandler instead of another AnimatorHandler.

```
public class AnimatorHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AnimatorHandler anim;  // <-- this should be an animator
```

eg.

```
public class AnimatorHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;
```